# Password as argument displayed in stack-trace

Tags: php, stack-trace

We log all the exception that occurs in our code, with the stack-trace associated.

The problem comes from this function:

```php
public function Authenticate($user, $password) {
    // Authenticate the user
}
```

When an exception is thrown by this function, the stack-trace contains the parameters used: the user password is displayed in plain text.

How can I deal with that? Should I rewrite Authenticate function to accept only encrypted password? Can I disallow this particular parameter to be displayed in stack trace?

Any idea is welcome.

**EDIT**

I use the [getTraceAsString](http://php.net/manual/fr/exception.gettraceasstring.php) function to log the trace.

Comment: Are you using the default Exception::getTrace()? xdebug has a [collect params](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#collect_params) setting, could be useful.

Comment: The one-second-hotfix would be wrap call to `Exception::getTraceAsString` with `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Exception::getTrace()](http://php.net/manual/tr/exception.gettrace.php) method to collect information, and write your own custom `getTraceAsString()`, not including parameters.

[See this example](http://php.net/manual/tr/exception.gettrace.php#98339) from the comments on [Exception::getTrace() docs](http://php.net/manual/tr/exception.gettrace.php).

```
  function MakePrettyException(Exception $e) {
    $trace = $e->getTrace();

    $result = 'Exception: "';
    $result .= $e->getMessage();
    $result .= '" @ ';
    if($trace[0]['class'] != '') {
      $result .= $trace[0]['class'];
      $result .= '->';
    }
    $result .= $trace[0]['function'];
    $result .= '();<br />';

    return $result;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer really help me, but this function just log the last function. I have chosen to use this one instead: http://php.net/manual/fr/exception.gettraceasstring.php#114980

Answer (score 5):

As of PHP 8.2 you can use the [SensitiveParameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sensitiveparameter.php#class.sensitiveparameter) attribute.

From the example on that page...

```
function defaultBehavior(
    string $secret,
    string $normal
) {
    throw new Exception('Error!');
}
```

with an error would give

> Exception: Error! in example.php:7 Stack trace:
> #0 example.php(19): defaultBehavior('password', 'normal')
> #1 {main}

Marking the secret as being sensitive...

```
function sensitiveParametersWithAttribute(
    #[\SensitiveParameter]
    string $secret,
    string $normal
) {
    throw new Exception('Error!');
}
```

gives

> Exception: Error! in example.php:15 Stack trace:
> #0 example.php(25): sensitiveParametersWithAttribute(Object(SensitiveParameterValue),
> 'normal')
> #1 {main}

Answer (score 1):

Two things I would suggest:

1. The stack trace should not be visible on the client end (if not already)
2. Authenticate should only accept a hashed version of the password

That way, even if someone has a copy of the hashed password, they can't use it to login, or use it to reverse the password.

The ideal method of course would be to use something like [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), where the default setting of [collect_params is 0](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#collect_params), meaning variables are not shown on the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks. The stack trace is not visible by the client, only by administrator, but they don't have to see the password of the user anyway. We use Xdebug, but only on our dev environment, not in production.

Comment: Hashing the password when calling authenticate isn't likely to work. Passwords should be salted, and you can't hash it until you do the lookup to get the salt. This presumably happens inside the Authenticate function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with an old PHP version and can't use `SensitiveParameter` then I'd refactor the code and replace password strings with anonymous functions.

In the ideal world, though, we would be able to get argument names from the stack trace and filter them out based by name!='password', etc.